# WSO2 IoT Server - Dashboard not show data

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-iot

I'm using WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 Update 5, and I've this problem: the Dashboad not show any data (and if I inspect with the developer with of Chrome, I found a lot of 404 errors)

When I open 
- myip:9443/devicemgt/ : Everything is OK.

But, If I open
- myip:9443/portal/dashboard : the dashboard not refresh any data

In the chrome's console I found a lot of HTTP 404

[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/portal/apis/xmlhttpclient 404 (Not Found)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmVbM.jpg)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portal app was depreciated with IoTS 3.1.0 GA Release and haven't maintained there after. It is not removed totally from product since it does have few internal dependencies. However portal app will completely remove from product with next major release.

Comment: Is there  any official announcement about that?

Comment: Is there  any official announcement about that?

The portal's access is still describe in the documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Accessing+the+WSO2+IoT+Server+Consoles), but using the port 9445 (Analitycs Port)... but, it has not any gadget (and the portal over 9443 yes it has!). So, How should it be configured?

Thanks

Comment: The portal running in analytics port (9445) is available to create your own dashboards and gadgets as needed. The old portal which was running over 9443 is depreciated as I have mentioned in my answer. Unfortunately there is no any public announcement made about that. However if you could describe your usecase with the portal, we might be able to provide you more details.

Comment: Thanks. My usecase is similar to the default's gadgets of old version. Is there any way to install the old gadgets (port 9443) into Analitycs installations (port 9445)?